# Why can a static nested class appear to have instance fields?

Tags: java, class, static, nested

Consider the following code in Java 8:

```
class OuterClass {

    static class MyStaticClass {

        static int staticInt = 5;
        int instanceInt = 6;
    }
}
```

Why is it that the static nested class can declare what appears to be an instance field, instanceInt?

Comment: Because you can create instances of static nested classes. Why should instance fields be restricted here?

Comment: "Static class" is just a class declaration that does not retain reference to parent class instance. So there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: *FYI:* They don't *"appear"* to have instance fields, they actually *do* have instance fields.

Comment: Usually when we ask "why is [something] possible?" it is good to include why we think that it shouldn't be possible. This way others can easier see and point out our mistakes or incorrect assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static nested class can refer to instance variables or methods defined in it through an object reference.

The below code is perfectly valid.

```
public class OuterClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass.MyStaticClass myStaticClassOne = new OuterClass.MyStaticClass();
        OuterClass.MyStaticClass myStaticClassTwo = new OuterClass.MyStaticClass();
        OuterClass.MyStaticClass myStaticClassThree = new OuterClass.MyStaticClass();
        myStaticClassOne.setInstanceInt(10);
        myStaticClassTwo.setInstanceInt(20);
        System.out.println("staticInt: " + MyStaticClass.staticInt);
        System.out.println("instanceIntOne: " + myStaticClassOne.getInstanceInt());
        System.out.println("instanceIntTwo: " + myStaticClassTwo.getInstanceInt());
        System.out.println("instanceIntThree: " + myStaticClassThree.getInstanceInt());

    }

    static class MyStaticClass {
        static int staticInt = 5;
        int instanceInt = 6;

        public int getInstanceInt() {
            return instanceInt;
        }

        public void setInstanceInt(int instanceInt) {
            this.instanceInt = instanceInt;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

staticInt: 5

instanceIntOne: 10

instanceIntTwo: 20

instanceIntThree: 6

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Would be a much better example if you actually show that *two* different instances can have different values for `instanceInt`

Comment: You are trying to show that static nested classes don't just "appear" to have instance fields, but actually *do* have them. You've done it by showing that you can create an instance of the nested class, but you haven't actually shown that the instance really do have instance fields. E.g. if OP believes that the `static` on the class implicitly makes all fields `static` too, you haven't disproved OP's misunderstanding with your example.

Comment: @Andreas: Thank you for your suggestions. I have included getter and setter for the instanceInt

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking why instanceInt can be declared and not be a static field? The answer is simply because there is no reason for Java to restrict that.

Here's a link to better understand what a static class is:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-class-in-java/